# How do I add node children to a TreeView using C# code?

Tags: c#, treeview

So I have a TreeView setup with a few nodes in it. I have a string list with a few strings in it, and I want to add the entire list into a child of a specific node in the TreeView using C# code (possibly a foreach loop?). How might I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This will add three nodes to the child node "node00" of node "node0"

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2", "string3" };

foreach (string s in strings)
    treeView1.Nodes["node0"].Nodes["node00"].Nodes.Add(s, s);
```

[image]

Note that you can specify the nodes by name (key) or by index

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the **WPF** TreeView or **WinForms** TreeView?

For WPF, the approach that worked best for me so far is to create a viewmodel and bind it to TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate. Basic idea is explained at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx.

WinForms TreeView can be manipulated directly through TreeView.Nodes, TreeNode.Nodes and such. I recommend against trying to do something similar with WPF TreeView...